# serial communication between arduino to 89c51 with gsm

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I need to connect the 89c51 with Arduino UNO but same time I need to connect 89c51 microcontroller with Arduino without using serial reception and transmission pins of UNO b'coz that pins already engage with GSM module. plz, suggest me the program solution to serially receive data from 89c51 and send the message to gsm module.

Comment: Use I2C, SPI or any other protocol?

Comment: There is always software serial.

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino Uno only has one (hardware) serial port. Since you need two, you have in principle two solutions:

- Use a software serial, this will work only for low speed transmissions. You can download this as a library.
- Use an Arduino (or other microcontroller) which has more than one hardware serial port, like the Arduino Mega which has 4.